# ReferenceError: 'styles' is not defined

Tags: react-native

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvmJz.jpg)

I get this error [in the screenshot] in my react-native project, and since the line doesn't really have "styles" in it, then I don't really know how this should be solved

here's the code block:

```
function SplashScreen({navigation}){
  return (
    <View style={{justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 90,
    alignItems:'center',
    alignContent:'center'}}>
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see any styles variable in your code. Could you show the full source file?

Comment: well that's the whole code https://snack.expo.io/@mai95/trembling-almond

Comment: Change let to const in line let styles = StyleSheet.create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using styles in SplashScreen but I'm not sure did you declare it. Pls check that

```
  <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOG IN</Text>
```

Comment: where else should I declare it?

Comment: just create new styles like in splash screen
```
const styles = Stylesheet.create({
     loginText : {}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your project in the console of the computer you may use a command like `npm run` or `expo start`, if you add  `-c` to either of these it should clear the cache and run the project, and maybe fix your issue.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, apologies it was very vague - I have updated the answer